# python sklearn tree classifier, what does each prediction function do?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Would someone please kindly explain what `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict(X)` and `.predict_log_proba(X)` and `.predict_proba(X)` are?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Here's the link to [sklearn's library:](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)

Comment: You already linked to the docs: what is unclear about these descriptions? Everything is described and the only function which might be unintuitive for non-ML people should be clear after reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability).

Answer (score 1):

In short words (and this applies to all sklearn models):

- `predict_proba(x)` = `P(y|x)` (probability of each label as a vector)
- `predict_log_proba(x)` = `log P(y|x)` (logarithm of the above)
- `predict(x)` = `arg max_y P(y|x)` (the most probable label using the above)

Comment: "the most probable label using the above" as in the maximum likelihood?

Comment: if you refer to "maximum likelihood estimation" then no. MLE is about finding a model which has a highest probability of data generation. This is the very basic arg max, simply "select value which has a highest probability". Thus in MLE it is the other way around, you look for theta such that P(x|theta) is maximal, and here you look for simple maximum posterior among already fitted probabilities.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!